# How can i click on image button with selenium - python

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing a selenium web driver program using `python`.
I need help to `click` on image button with `selenium` in `python`.

My `html` page info is as follows:

```
<code>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="location.href='Yad2Edit.php?SalesID=11847965&amp;leumiCardEnabled=0'">
      <img style="border: 0px;" src="http://images.yad2.co.il/Pic/site_images/yad2/MyYad2/images/myorderbottom/new/edit_ad.png" alt="">
    </a>
</code>
```

Comment: Can you edit your code please ?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967097/click-on-buttons-with-images